# how to get the object_id from post_id in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, objectid

I think this is a simple question but I am not able to get the answer for the same.
I know 'get_queried_object_id()' gets the object id for current post id BUT I need to get object_id for parent id of current post id. Is this possible ?

I want something like below.

```
global $post;
$parent_id = $post->post_parent;
if ( 0 != $parent_id ) {
    get object_id of $parent_id
}
```

Any help/suggestions are welcome.